# How to assign cart data in order Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I am successfully save custom data in cart using **checkout_cart_product_add_after** event in "**quote_item_option**" table Now i want to save this data in order and display in order section in admin panel.

[image]

Comment: Share your code which you have use for save data

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to save additional option to order item.

in `etc/events.xml` add following code.

`<event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
     <observer name="vendor_module_sales_model_service_quote_submit_before" instance="Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitBeforeObserver" />
 </event>`

and in `SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitBeforeObserver.php` file add below code.

```
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $this->quote = $observer->getQuote();
        $this->order = $observer->getOrder();
        foreach($this->order->getItems() as $orderItem)
        {
            if(!$orderItem->getParentItemId() && $orderItem->getProductType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE)
            {

                if($quoteItem = $this->getQuoteItemById($orderItem->getQuoteItemId())){
                    if ($additionalOptionsQuote = $quoteItem->getOptionByCode('additional_options'))
                    {
                        if($additionalOptionsOrder = $orderItem->getProductOptionByCode('additional_options'))
                        {
                            $additionalOptions = array_merge($additionalOptionsQuote, $additionalOptionsOrder);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $additionalOptions = $additionalOptionsQuote;
                        }
                        if(count($additionalOptions) > 0)
                        {
                            $options = $orderItem->getProductOptions();
                            $options['additional_options'] = $this->serialize->unserialize($additionalOptions->getValue());
                            $orderItem->setProductOptions($options);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private function getQuoteItemById($id)
    {
        if(empty($this->quoteItems))
        {
            foreach($this->quote->getItems() as $item)
            {
                if(!$item->getParentItemId() && $item->getProductType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE)
                {
                    $this->quoteItems[$item->getId()] = $item;
                }
            }
        }
        if(array_key_exists($id, $this->quoteItems))
        {
            return $this->quoteItems[$id];
        }
        return null;
    }
```

for more details, you can check these links

https://magecomp.com/blog/add-additional-options-magento-2/

https://webkul.com/blog/additional-options-order-item-magento2/

Comment: I will try and let you know...!